# C# Reflection, how to get the value of a composite object

Tags: c#

I have a patient object which has a statement object. I want to get the values of all patient object and statement object using reflection.

```
public class Patient
{    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Address { get; set; }    
    public Statement Statement { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Is this HL7 patient data (medical records)?  It is XML format

Comment: Why do you need to use reflection if you know type of the object?

Comment: No, just one Patient object

Comment: If you are trying to keep tracking every existing patient i think you should add them to any `IEnumerable<Patient>` uppon creation (so within the ctor) and the check this object. I think you should add the definition of the `Statement` class to your question

Comment: No, lets say Statement has statement number. I want to get the property Name and Value of both Patient and Statement

Comment: public static void PrintProps(Patient patient)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = patient.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
            }
        }

Comment: this will give me Patient's properties not Statement. I want both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `Statement` property value of an object using reflection:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = 
    object.GetType().GetProperty("Statement", BindingFlags.Instance);

object statement = property.GetValue(object);
```

But since you already know all the details of `Patient` and `Statement` what's the point using reflection?